# loading titan graph database with mogwai

Tags: python, titan, gremlin

Im trying to start learning Gremlin to communicate with a titan db 0.5.4, and since Im gonna use mogwai to execute the the gremlin queries later, so i thought its better to learn both of them side by side. but I stuck at the first step. I couldn't know how to load the graph of the gods.

> Gremlin query:
>
> gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('titan-berkeleydb-es.properties')

while Im reading the mogwai [docs](http://mogwai.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/gremlin.html) I found this class:

> class mogwai.gremlin.base.GremlinMethod(path=None, method_name=None, classmethod=False, property=False, defaults=None, transaction=True, imports=None)
>
> Gremlin method that returns a graph element
>
> configure_method(klass, attr_name, gremlin_path)
> Sets up the methods internals

Im not sure if this is the right approach, and if its, Im not sure how to pass the parameters .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the quickstart: http://mogwai.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Also additional examples showing the use of GremlinMethods http://mogwai.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/example_groovy_imports.html http://mogwai.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/gremlin.html